# What are the base circles called (decimal, duodecimal, hexadecimal)?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, terminology

So we were talking about different bases and one of my friends brought up this circle diagram where you write all the numbers in a base (for decimal it would be 1-9) in a circle.  Then you create the next circle of numbers around the first one by doubling all the numbers and summing digits for any two-digit numbers.  So the next circle would be 2, 4, 6, 8, 1, 3, 5, 7, 9.  If you keep doing this, then some of the rays going out from the center of the circles make nice repeating patterns.  For example, 1-2-4-8-7-5-1 repeats itself.  9-9-9-9-9 always stays as itself (9*2=18; 1+8=9).  3-6-3-6-3-6 is another one (3*2=6; 6*2=12; 1+2=3).

You could do this with a base other than 10.  For example, with base 5, your first circle would be 1-4.  Next would be 2, 4, 2, 4 (since in base 5, 3*2=11; 1+1=2, and 4*2=13; 1+3=4).  Next would be 4, 4, 4, 4.  And then all subsequent concentric circles would be all 4's.

I want to find out more about these "circle diagrams". Does anyone know if they have a name, and if so, what they're called?

Comment: So, the operation you're doing is `double, then take digit sum`?

Comment: Sounds like the powers of two modulo $b-1$. Do you put the $b-1$ classes/digits at the corners of a regular polygon and draw the diagonals that correspond to "doubling"?

Comment: Not quite. If we were operating $mod (b-1)$, 9 could never be an element in the sequence in the base 10 circle. However, with the addition of 0 in the circle, we can comfortably operate $mod\,b$

Comment: @sredmond Sure, $9$ is just another name for $0$ when we work modulo $9$. Think of a traditional clock where the "zero point" is marked $12$, and the other numbers, in clockwise order, are $1$ through $11$. On that disk, calculating modulo $12$ (or $13-1$ if you prefer), the sequence from $12$ of course is constant. The sequence from $1$ goes like this: $1,2,4,8,4,8,\ldots$. The sequence from $3$ goes $3,6,12,12,12,\ldots$. The sequence from $5$ goes $5,10,8,4,8,4,\ldots$. These can be drawn as diagonal arrows in the dodecagon. A kind of irregular dodecagram.

Comment: So we can call it $(2^k - 1) \, \textrm{mod} \, (b-1) + 1$

Answer (score 1):

I don't know precisely what these are called, but you can always use the [OEIS](http://oeis.org/) (Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences) to lookup a given sequence to see its name (if it exists) and some cool properties.

If you're working base $n$, I think you should include 0 on your circle. While it's true that loops beginning with 0 are never interesting (0->0->0->0...), if you include 0, the sequence has some nice properties. With the addition of zero, the kth (0-indexed) element of the loop is $2^{k}mod\,n$. For base ten, the loop would be $(1,2,4,8,6,2,4,8,6,2,...)$. This sequence shows interesting behavior, in that the number one leads to a cycle of which it is not a member.

Some interesting questions to ponder: Given base n, what is the longest cycle? Which numbers lead to a cycle in which they are not included? Are we guaranteed that, for any starting number, we will eventually enter some loop? Why or why not?

Comment: Thanks! I didn't think to look up based on the particular number sequence. This is what I found: http://vortexmath.webs.com/apps/blog/entries/show/5475132-introduction-to-vortex-based-math-vbm-

Comment: Vortex math is arithmetic BS. Avoid.